# Why is recordcount always -1?

Tags: vb.net, adodb

I have the following code and no matter how I tweak it I always get back -1 as the record count.

```
gcnnPETS.Open()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
rs = gcnnPETS.Execute("SELECT Title FROM tblEmp")

Messagebox.show(rs.RecordCount.tostring)
gcnnPETS.Close()
```

I've been working on this all day and no matter what I do I always get -1 for the record count even though there are hundreds of records in the table. If I paste the query into SSMS it returns the records just fine. I know I'm doing something wrong but at this point I can't figure it out. Any thoughts or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: ADODB does not actually calculate the number of record returned by a select. That field only have a correct value once you have iterated over all the elements. So you can either use `MoveLast` to go to the end or change your query to a `COUNT(*)` if you really only need to have the number

Comment: You have to `MoveLast` to get an accurate count

Comment: I would love an example of using movelast to get the record/row count. I'm looking on the net but haven't found a good example yet. Thank you!

Comment: Literally just `rs.MoveLast` before your `MessageBox` call.

Comment: This may be a typo; however, you are trying to get the count on `dan.RecordCount`  and using the variable `rs` to store the recordset.  In addition to what the others have stated, see: [RecordCount Property (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordcount-property-ado)

Comment: Yes TnTinMn I was trying to sanitize my post. Dan = rs as you correctly noted.

Comment: Bradley Uffner if I do that I get Rowset does not support fetching backward.

Comment: I think you mean `rs.Open("SELECT Title FROM tblEmp", gcnnPETS)`

Comment: braX that's just a short way to do the same thing. I'm not having a problem opening a connection or running a query I'm having a problem getting the number of rows in the recordset.